# Download To excel functionality through an iframe element renders inconsistently

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-9

i have an iframe element

```
<iframe id='excelIframe' src=''></iframe>
```

now on click of a button i make an ajax call and allow the user to download a report using this iframe element and the following jquery:

```
$("#excelIframe").attr('src', 'ABC.ashx?requestType=xyz' + ClientId);
```

It has been working fine for a long time now but recently some IE9 clients are having problems downloading the file.

Comment: What are the problems some IE9 clients are having when downloading the file?

Comment: the file that is downloaded is an excel file but it is labeled ABC the name of the ashx file and when it opens it tries to access the ashx file in our repository and crashes

Answer (score 1):

In your ashx add

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DesiredFileName.xlsx")
```